# Does this sentence violate the 'be nice' policy?

Tags: discussion, chat, election, be-nice-policy

In a chat at a site where an election was held, they were commenting the fact that only half of the members who visited the polls (earning the *Caucus* badge) had gotten the *Constituent* badge, and therefore actually cast a ballot.

1. one user explained it saying: "*..they couldn't find a palatable candidate*"
2. another wrote: "*...It's better to not vote than to elect somebody who will do damage*"

This site is frequented by mods of many SE sites. Can you tell me if that policy is implemented with same strictness on all sites and chat-rooms and if there is any chance the above chat messages may be considered offensive or *inappropriate*, and, if reported, a censure to their authors might ensue?

I take (the votes mean) that nobody thinks the above statements are inappropriate and they should not possibly be sanctioned.

Comment: FYI the [tag:comments] tag is for actual comments made on questions or answers. For chat messages, there is a different tag.

Comment: Why don't you ask this question on that specific site Meta? Be nice policy is very subjective and some get away with worse comments than them and some get suspended for milder comments. That's the way SE works. I think you should ask them first.

Comment: I cannot see how voicing an opinion about an election candidate (unless it is an irrelevant personal attack) is in any way a bad thing. That is the whole point of elections.

Comment: BTW, what is the purpose of your asking this question? What do you want to know?

Comment: Are you sure these comments weren't about the US presidential election? I'm pretty sure I said the same thing about that last week

Comment: @Fiksdal, they are pretty basic and obvious comments, sure! The point is that the first statement was censured with an official warning, and it really seemed insane to me. I wanted to check if there is anyone who could possibly agree with that decision.

Comment: @AlbertI First of all, mentioning the US election was meant as a joke. Secondly do you mean that one of these statements **was** removed by mods, and you are asking whether that is correct? You should probably make that more clear in OP. I believe the reason you have gotten downvoted for this is because people may think you're wondering whether such comments **should** be removed.

Comment: @Fiksdal, I know you upvoted, but the downvotes here at Meta mean readers disagree that the sentences violate any policy. I asked the question in a neutral form. The statement was moved to *thrash* and the author got an official warning. The neutral form elicited unbiassed response, if you think the sentences are OK you should have downvoted!

Comment: @Rathony, It useless to question a mod decision at that site, you can only become a target.

Comment: @AlbertI I don't vote that way. I upvote when I feel questions are **useful**, and I upvoted your question for that very reason. In order to express my opinion, I vote on the **answers**. There are some exceptions to this, such as when the question has a very opinionated tone and I disagree.

Comment: Why do you think it is useless? What's wrong with becoming a target? I don't understand. I just wanted to let you know as your question received too many downvotes. Good luck.

Comment: There are many problems with wording an intended open-ended question in a way that attracts downvotes. For example, you may lose reputation, attract automatic question bans, cause the question to be hidden from the front page due to low score, etc.

Comment: @Fiksdal,not on Meta, here votes carry no rep, they are only a quick way to express dis/-agreement on the view in the question

Comment: @AlbertI Unlike the site-specific metas, votes do carry rep here on the main Meta SE. And [as you can see](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/271304/albert-i?tab=reputation), you've actually lost rep from asking this useful question. If these voters had understood your actual intention, I don't believe they would have downvoted.

Answer (score 20):

I'm not a moderator on any site, but spent a while around and learned a thing or two.

From my experience, and own point of view, such a sentence is valid in chat:

- It's not directed towards any specific person.
- It's just a general statement that is result of frustration, and said in context of the elections.

Actually even saying something like "I believe John Doe will cause damage as a moderator" is valid in my opinion, it's part of having elections: people should be allowed to express their feelings. It's not saying "John Doe is stupid", which is indeed invalid.

Comment: Thanks, that is a very profound analysis, if I read you correctly you are saying that the second comment is more harsh, but it is not inappropriate, and even a direct mention of a specific candidate as a potential cause of damage is fully appropriate. right? is discipline looser in chatrooms, or it makes no difference?

Comment: True for both your questions. And yes, chat in general is more "flexible" and less strict, though it's really different between each room.